# php echo with product id does not display both to the html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 php codes with 2 different `product_id`. If I select the block that represent one of the 2 id's and then chose a block that represent the left over product_id this code will only display the last chosen `product_id`.

This code is for adding a product to the shopping cart. So when a chose a product with the id `product_id_subscribtion` and after that I chose a product with `product_id_seperate` it will only display the product with the id `product_id_seperate`.

Btw I use the get method to form the `$_COOKIE`:

```
<?php    

    $getUsers = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM productssubscription WHERE product_id = ?");
    $getUsers->execute(array($_COOKIE['product_id_subscribtion']));
    $users = $getUsers->fetchAll();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo "<h1>" . $user['amount'] . " Panty's per maand"   . "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>" . "Prijs: " . $user['price'] . "</h1>";
  }
    ?>
```

and this

```
<?php    

    $getUsers = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM productsseperate WHERE product_id = ?");
    $getUsers->execute(array($_COOKIE['product_id_seperate']));
    $users = $getUsers->fetchAll();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo "<h1>" . $user['amount'] . " Panty's"   . "</h1>";
        echo "<h1>" . "Prijs: " . $user['price'] . "</h1>";
    }



    ?>
```